# How to get coverage from Bazel by running the program instead of writing unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, code-coverage, bazel, bazel-cpp

My project is build by Bazel. Except for the unit test for every single function, it sometimes needs testing in some scenes like the simulation of the user's input as a black box testing. To ensure the testing scene is complex enough to find  vulnerabilities, I want to know the coverage of some testing scenes.

I try to avoid writing unit tests, like using LLVM flags `-fprofile-instr-generate -fcoverage-mapping` and running the test program directly, interacting with the program, and then getting coverage.
I read from Bazel's documents know the coverage command runs the unit test to get coverage, but can I directly get coverage from a running program?

Comment: I don't think you can get coverage from a running program directly. Bazel coverage command to process the coverage profile file and that will generate a report.The coverage report will provide information on the coverage of your testing scenes, including which lines of code were executed and which were not.

Comment: @SG_Bazel Sounds bad. Obviously, Bazel finally uses clang and clang++ to compile, and they support `-fprofile-instr-generate -fcoverage-mapping`, and you can see the coverage report after running the program. I think it should not be difficult to implement this function, it only needs to add the flag at compile time, and don't have to do anymore.